# Regex search fails

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm using boolean logic for my regex search but it's not working. Specifically, the "and not" part of the expression is not working.

Example: `Gi3/3` should match, but `Gi3/3(P)` should NOT match.

```
for line in infile:
   int = re.search(r"Gi\d\/.+", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE) or re.search(r"Eth\d\/.+", line) and not re.search(r"^Gi\d\/.+\(P\)$", line)
```

When above code is executed, I see matches on `Gi3/3(P)` and I don't expect this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remove '+' from your regex

```
for line in infile:
int = re.search(r"Gi\d\/.", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE) or re.search(r"Eth\d\/.", line) and not re.search(r"^Gi\d\/.\(P\)$", line)
```

Comment: You know, funny thing is your solution actually worked, but whoever voted you down probably would have liked to have seen the optimal answer.

Comment: My intention was to keep your logic same.

Comment: Trust me, I know. Personally, some people here get a bit of pleasure pushing that downvote button. I didn't and wouldn't have - I see exactly what you did and I personally like it, but I have to acknowledge that the regex would still easily be broken with little nuance.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one reguar expression with *lookahead* that is catching all three conditions:

```
re.search(r"(Gi|Eth)\d/\d+(?=>\D|$)", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: The question was kind of badly asked especially in light of the accepted answer